# Removing popup at forcepasteasplaintext

Tags: html, ckeditor, sap-commerce-cloud, fckeditor

I was configuring the FCKEditor in the productcockpit of hybris so that there will be no HTML markup in the text when pasting it into the popup window.

Is there any way to remove that popup which is coming as soon as you paste some stuff into it? Or is there still the issue with browser security and js stuff?

Answer (score 0):

The paste dialogs were removed in CKEditor 4.7.0 (see [changelog](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/CHANGES.md#ckeditor-47) and https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/16954). You may also just force pasting plain text with [forcePasteAsPlainText](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-forcePasteAsPlainText) config option.

But this is for CKEditor 4.x, if you are using FCKEditor you may consider updating to the newest version of CKEditor.